# Frobenius Norm of Projected Matrix

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $A$ be a matrix of dimension $K \times N$ with complex entries. If $P$ is an idempotent projection matrix such that $P^H = P$, can we say that 
$Tr (APA^H)^{-1} \ge Tr(A A^H)^{-1}$?

Note that the projection matrix, $P$, has the dimension of $N \times N$ and the rank $K$.

The case for $K=1$ is trivial as the projection of a vector always has the norm less than that of the vector itself. Any clue for the general result?